# Check files in from VIM?

Tags: svn, vim, cvs

Directly from vim, is there a way to check files into cvs or subversion?

I know I can just use a different console window to check in any changes, but it is so much more convenient to be able to do everything from the same window, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a vim svn integration script [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=90), but I have no experience with it.  I'm pretty sure you can bang the command if you're in the active working directory.

```
!svn commit file.blah
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to just type in the !svn or !cvs command directly from vim! Didn't realize it would support that :)

Comment: I don't use svn, but I mapped my common checkin commands to keys I can use, which automatically fill the current filename in for me.

Answer (score 5):

There are tons of plugins on [the script archive](http://www.vim.org/scripts/) for this exact purpose.  [vcscommand.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=90) is one I know I've heard people use before to abstract themselves from the specific vcs they are using.